# USA FLAG Got the code don't know how to make it colorful

Tags: python

So I got this code to make an USA Flag but I don't know how to make the stripes red.
Please make the answers as simple as possible as I am new to python so I dont get a lot of things
This is a school project and I need it in 2 days.
Please help and thanks in advance

```
       import turtle
    import time
    import random

def draw_rectangle(length, height):
    turtle.up()
    x = -150
    y = 150
    C = height*(7/13)
    D = length*(2/5)
    L = stripe_width = float(round(height/13,1))

    ## Draw rectangle first.
    turtle.color(0,0,0)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.setpos(x,y)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.end_fill()

    ## Then draw the stripes.
    x1 = -150
    y1 = 150-L
    for z in range(13):
        if z%2 == 0:
            r = s = t = 0
        else:
            r = s = t = 1
        turtle.up()
        turtle.speed(100)
        turtle.setpos(x1,y1)
        turtle.setheading(90)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.color(r,s,t)
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(L)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(L)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.end_fill()
        y1 -= L

    ## Finally draw the stars rectangle overlapping the stripes, next is stars.
    x2 = -150+D
    y2 = 150.5-C
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x2,y2)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color(0,0,0)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(D)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(C)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(D)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(C)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.up()

    turtle.bye
    draw_star(-length, height)

def draw_star(l, h):
    for z in range(50):
        if z < 7:
            row = 140
            draw_starrows(row)
        if z < 14:
            row = row - 20
            draw_starrows(row)
        if z < 21:
            row = row - 20
            draw_starrows(row)
        if z < 28:
            row = row - 20
            draw_starrows(row)
        if z < 35:
            row = row - 20
            draw_starrows(row)
            ## This gets the turtle pen out of the way at the very end.
            turtle.up()
            turtle.setpos(-180,100)
        break

def draw_starrows(row):
    x = -160
    y = 150
    for z in range(10):
        x += 15
        turtle.up()
        turtle.color(1,1,1)
        turtle.speed(100)
        turtle.setpos(x,row)
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.down()
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.bye

##def get_color():
##    r = g = b = 0
##    color = r = g = b
##    return color

def draw_flag():
    A = 200
    height = int(A)
##    length = height*1.9
##    C = height*(7/13)
##    D = length*(2/5)
##    E = F = union_height/10
##    G = H = union_length/12
##    stripe_width = height/13
##    diameter_star = stripe_width*(4/5)
    draw_rectangle(height*1.9, height)

draw_flag()
```

Comment: does not `turtle.color` set the pen color? try calling `turtle.color("red")`

Comment: This is not a free homework site. Do your own homework.

Comment: Breitbart.com forum might be able to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The three inputs on `turtle.color()` are the red, green and blue components of the color. When drawing the stripes you're setting the three components to 0 (black) or 1 (white). If the red component is always 1, those colors will be 1,0,0 (red) or 1,1,1 (white):

```
turtle.color(1,s,t)
```

And if you want the stars on a blue background, set the color to:

```
turtle.color(0,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a bit of a simpler code, that results in a coloured flag;

```
import turtle
import time
import random

def draw_rectangle(length, height):
    turtle.up()
    x = -150
    y = 150
    C = height*(7/13)
    D = length*(2/5)
    L = stripe_width = float(round(height/13,1))


    turtle.color('blue')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.setpos(x,y)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.end_fill()


    x1 = -150
    y1 = 150-L
    for z in range(13):
        if z%2 == 0:
            r = ('red')
        else:
            r = ('white')
        turtle.up()
        turtle.speed(100)
        turtle.setpos(x1,y1)
        turtle.setheading(90)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.color(r)
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(L)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(L)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.end_fill()
        y1 -= L

    x2 = -150+D
    y2 = 150.5-C
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x2,y2)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color('blue')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(D)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(C)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(D)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(C)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.up()

    turtle.bye
    draw_star(-length, height)

def draw_star(l, h):
    for z in range(50):
        if z < 7:
            row = 140
            draw_starrows(row)
        if z < 14:
            row = row - 20
            draw_starrows(row)
        if z < 21:
            row = row - 20
            draw_starrows(row)
        if z < 28:
            row = row - 20
            draw_starrows(row)
        if z < 35:
            row = row - 20
            draw_starrows(row)
            turtle.up()
            turtle.setpos(-180,100)
        break

def draw_starrows(row):
    x = -160
    y = 150
    for z in range(10):
        x += 15
        turtle.up()
        turtle.color('white')
        turtle.speed(100)
        turtle.setpos(x,row)
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.down()
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.forward(6.154)
        turtle.left(144)
        turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.bye

def draw_flag():
    A = 200
    height = int(A)
    draw_rectangle(height*1.9, height)

draw_flag()
```